# Подключения при закрытом порте

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема. Можно ли как-нибудь подключиться через другой порт к другу. Если у него порт sql закрыт.

Comment: 1. Это не проблема, а вопрос  
2. К друзьям через порты SQL не подключаются  
3. Подключитесь к нему через порт USB или LAN :)  
4. Воспользуйтесь сканером портов, посмотрите какие порты открыты у Вашего друга и подключайтесь на любой открытый

Comment: Воспользуйтесь сканером портов, посмотрите какие порты открыты у Вашего друга и подключайтесь на любой открытый

а как подключиться? через что

Comment: @naik127 socket

Comment: как с ним работать?

Comment: @naik127
Зачем терроризировать людей?) Есть гугл который с радостью поможет новичкам. [Что такое сокет?](http://masandilov.ru/network/guide_to_network_programming__what_is_socket)

Comment: А что такое порт sql?

Comment: @alexlz наверно это порт на котором работает SQL-сервер. Обычно 1433

Comment: Смотря какой SQL сервер. У MySQL по умолчанию 3306, например.

И вообще, что значит "подключиться к другу?". Подключиться к sql базе, которая находится у друга? Так может решение проблемы не в том как подключиться по закрытому порту, как открыть этот порт?

Comment: О! Появился первый нормальный наводящий вопрос. И что ответит стартёр топика? (Блин, когда вопрошающие будут хотя бы немного стараться формулировать вопрос?)

Comment: @alexlz, весьма злободневный вопрос, может поднимете на всеобщее рассмотрение с меткой [ХешКодъ]?

Comment: @karmadro4 А смысл? Любой вьюношь/дэвушк может прочитать это в правилах, и если бы у них было время/желание над правилами подумать, а не бояться, что их примут за первоклассников из-за отсутствия недомолвок и "профжаргона", то, может быть, они бы и пытались (результат при этом был бы вряд ли сильно лучше, но обид на наводящие вопросы -- меньше). А этот вопрос с меткой "Хэшкод" каждый новичок будет стараться прочесть в первую очередь?

Comment: @alexlz, я имел ввиду выработать меры противодействия, например, закрывать бестолковые вопросы вместо того, чтобы устраивать допросы. Кстати, правил как таковых вообще нет.

Comment: Если закрывать вопрос, то спрашивающий просто обидится. Если допытаться, что он хочет, то есть вероятность, что в следующий раз он(а) спросит уже с учётом первого опыта. А правила -- будут ли их читать? (Ср. с лицензионными соглашениями на варезы).

Comment: @alexlz, но есть и вероятность, что вопрошающий воспримет наводящие вопросы как должное и продолжит действовать по старой успешной схеме. Поэтому и предлагаю вынести на широкое обсуждение, чтобы была возможность выработать компромисс, который устроит все стороны. Например, принимая закрытие вопроса слишком жесткой мерой, можно показывать кол-во голосов за закрытие, что будет недвусмысленно намекать о необходимости отредактировать вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

1. Возьмите сканер портов и посмотрите какие порты у него открыты. А еще лучше попросить его открыть нужный вам порт (пропишите правила в файрволле)
2. Настройте на SQL вашего друга через какой порт будет общаться сервер БД с внешним миром